# d3 create svg from JSON paths

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I have a json file which contain multiple paths

**Json file**

```
{
    "paths": {
        "path1": {
            "name": "PathName1",
            "path": "m 411.42,469.19 -0.98 ... z",
        },
        "path2": {
            "name": "PathName2",
            "path": "m 396.03,243.46 1.48,0.11 0,0 -0.01,0.47 -0.95,1.45 ... z",
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to create an svg from this Json file using d3, but I don't know how to use my paths

```
var svg = d3.select('#map').append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);


d3.json("urlToJsonFile", function(req, data) {
    // how can I show my paths ?
}
```

Comment: My question is the following. Do you need help with the JSON part of this or the D3 part?

Comment: create path elements and set their d attributes to the path values from the JSON

Comment: Check the source on this. Let me know: https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/intgraphs/intgraph.004.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several paths, and want to draw them all, you might want to parse your JSON data into a collection to use data()/enter()/exit() joins (or process them in a loop or use some other optimisation technique).

To use the data in the JSON structure you provided you can path objects, bind each "path" object as "datum", and pass the path data to its "d" attribute. This will draw one of your paths:

```
svg.append("path")
   .attr("class", "path1")
   .datum(data.paths.path1)
   .attr("d", function(d) { return d.path});
```

Try it out: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/v2xw9dhq/)

Comment: Do you know how can I use `data()` in this case to avoid doing a loop ?

Comment: The `data()` function is used with arrays. See [D3 Documentation - selection.data][https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections#data]. If your `paths` object is actually a list of similar `path` objects, you can pre-process your JSON file and reorganize the data as an array (a simple for-loop could be used, for example).